# How to call a REST service using PUT method in Mule?

Tags: rest, mule, mule-studio, put, anypoint-studio

Below is my flow. I need to call a REST service using PUT method. Using the same json request and the same service url it is working fine from Postman, but from Mule I am getting the error: "Cannot PUT /api/sms/send". Can someone please tell me what is wrong ?

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

     <mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
         xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.7.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
         <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8093" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
         <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="api.example.com" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
         <flow name="testprojectFlow">
             <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
             <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                 <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
     %output application/json
     ---
     {
         message_id: "d5c9af23-f1b2-4d5e-9d6b-439371e0009a",
         dst_number: "1234567890",
         src_number: "1234567891",
         message_type: "SMS:TEXT",
         message_data:  "TEST MESSAGE SMS API",
         submit_date: now
     }]]></dw:set-payload>
             </dw:transform-message>
             <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api/sms/send" method="PUT" doc:name="HTTP"/>
             <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         </flow>
     </mule>
```

Comment: Welcome to Mule in StockOverflow!!  Provide more information on error details.Paste here 3 to 4 lines of exception detail for help answering.

Comment: @star thank you. This is the exception in the mule console: org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 404 mapped as failure.

and this is the payload after the failing : "Cannot PUT /api/sms/send"

Comment: are you sure you are using a valid destination path? 404 sounds like destination not found. Are you able to make same call from postman or other tool?